# JODConverter 3 converter webservice

Tags: php, web-services, jar, jodconverter

Has anyone built one of these on a stock Windows Server 2008 r2 ? I only ask because JODConverter 3 doesn't seem to have the web services that v2 had, and the references ot getting them running talk about .jar files which don't seem to exist. If it can't be done using TomCat or something similar, it might be possible to construct a .php wrapper that calls the command line - but that option seems to defeat the purpose. Any ideas gratefully welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

If you grab the read only from [svn](http://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/source/checkout) there is an example web application that you can compile with maven.
Executing the .jar from php using exec was unreliable at best when I tried it, it's not how it was intended to be used.

[Here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/jodconverter/9bzKcvOvK-c) is an example php class someone made for use with a the web service method.

After fiddling around I've decided that a java application was the best route for us, but that is mainly due to restrictions of my project (not being allowed to run a TomCat server for example).

Comment: To clarify by exectuting the .jar I mean using the test provided in the wiki (java -jar lib/jodconverter-core-3.0-beta-4.jar test.odt test.pdf)

Comment: Argh. What a world of pain. I have no experience with Maven. Think I've got everything installed. Tried building the test app, and hit a wall of unresolved dependencies...

Comment: Not sure what `<dependency>
      <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
      <artifactId>jodconverter-core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>` references in the pom.xml file

Comment: Doh! I need to build the core as well as the app (although I have the core installed elsewhere)

Comment: I had to build core, I used the -DskipTests flag as one of the tests failed. But that gave me the required jodconverter-core-3.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

Comment: Yup - doing that now. For reference, the command was `mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean install`

Comment: So I now have a .war file (renamed as converter.war) which I just need to drop into my tomcat\bin folder, and restart right?

Comment: That sounds right, you're further down the path than I went. Good luck :)